# Cloth Brush making holes when using Multires

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution, sculpt-mode, brushes

I was trying to use the Cloth Brush to add some detail to clothes, but it was creating holes instead.

I tested in a new file and it seems to still be happening. The Cloth Brush works fine if I just subdivide it. But when I use Multires, it just creates holes. (PS: It works fine if Multires's Sculpt is set to 0)

[image]

The plane on the left is the one with multires, the plane on the right is only subdivided.

Here's the file I used
[image]

Is it not possible to use the Cloth Brush when using Multires?

Answer (score 1):

I found that ticking the checkbox *Sculpt Base Mesh* in the *Multiresolution Modifier* settings fixes this issue.